# Unexpected Linq OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following test which is failing:

```
[TestCase]
public void Should_order_numeric_suffix()
{
    var names = new List<string>
                    {
                        "Buisness Unit 7",
                        "Business Unit 1",
                        "Buisness Unit 3",
                        "Business Unit 6",
                        "Business Unit 4",
                        "Buisness Unit 2",
                        "Business Unit 5"
                    };

    List<string> ordered = names.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

    Assert.That(ordered[0], Is.EqualTo("Business Unit 1"));
}
```

The actual order of the ordered List is:

```
Business Unit 2
Business Unit 3
Business Unit 7
Business Unit 1
Business Unit 4
Business Unit 5
Business Unit 6
```

Obviously it is ordering alphabetically correctly but I expected the numeric suffix to be ordered also.

Comment: You have typos in your code: `Buisness` vs. `Business`. When that is taken into account the ordering is totally fine.

Comment: Note that even after fixing the typos it will sort `BU 10` before `BU 2`

Comment: Note there is no 10 in question.

Comment: Ha, that is funny, I did not enter the data into the database where I pulled the data for the test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have typos in your list, some entries spell "Buisness" instead of "Business"... and "Buisness" comes before "Business" in alphabetical order

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though :-P

Comment: Why the downvote? It is the correct explanation for the behavior the OP is seeing...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for natural sort order, which is not by default implemented in GroupBy
You will need to implement a custom IComparer.

Of course those allready exist e.g:

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html?showComment=1258020708758#c5034722582649839449

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite the query like this:

```
List<string> ordered = (from n in names
                        orderby n
                        select n).ToList<string>();
```